# Losing ref in useEffect hook after setTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to play an animation if requested by the prop after mounting the component. But my ref seems to be getting reset to null after a setTimeout.

```js
    let landingText = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
    //ref shows div element here
        setTimeout(() => {
        //ref gets reset to null here
            if (!onShow) {
                playAnimation();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }, []);
```

I have fixed this by adding a new variable and passing it down -

```js
    useEffect(() => {
        const el = landingText;
        setTimeout(() => {
```

But I was curious as to why this would be happening after a setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

That happens cause in the second argument in `useEffect` u just put empty array `[]` it's should be adding `onShow` in the second argument of useEffect